# How to optimize writing to a large table in Hive/HDFS using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, optimization, hive, hdfs

I face a common problem when trying to write a large table in Hive/HDFS from a source table containing 24 billion rows.

The Spark job applies a `Window` function to retrieve only the latest states for each key in the source table. I end up having to insert around 11 billion rows in the target table.

The tables are partitioned on a dated field in `YYYYMM` format named `dt_part`.

The picture below is the data writing Stage:

[image]

This Stage is very long and gets bogged down at the end without any data being written down.

The data writing function is as follows:

```
df
  .write
  .partitionBy("dt_part")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .saveAsTable(targetTable)
```

For information, the Spark job has the following resources (dynamic allocation):

- Driver memory = 15 G
- Executor memory = 16 G
- Executor cores = 8
- Max number of executors = 80
- `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` = 10000

I have tested several values of the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (250, 3000 and 20000) but the result remains the same, I can't write the data in a resonable timeframe.

Do you have any suggestions for optimising the writing process?

Comment: Partitionby afaicr does not cause shuffle.

Comment: ...and your screenshot is not that of data writing stage. I'd start by figuring out why do you have 30,000 tasks at this point.

Comment: @mazaneicha we were soldiers

Comment: @thebluephantom nothing changes, hold the line! :)

Comment: Pls add code and some data samples